# Flutter Plugin Throwing Error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've been attempting to use the plugin "livechatt" found at https://pub.dev/packages/livechatt in my Flutter application. I had no issue getting it to work in the Android release, but on iOS, it fails in the same way every time.

I imported the package in my `pubspec.yaml` the same way I have with every other plugin. When running the app in the iOS simulator from Android Studio, the build succeeds, but the app crashes immediately after boot. When running the app from Xcode, the build succeeds, but the app freezes on the launch-splash screen.

**NOTE: As it stands, the plugin does have an error with its dependency in iOS, so those testing it will need to change the target OS from iOS 9.0 to iOS 11.0 in `livechatt.podspec`, and then run `pod install` in the project's iOS directory to sync the changes**

Xcode then displays the following errors:

Error 4
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee7ce5ff8)` in `ios\.symlinks\plugins\livechatt\ios\classes\LiveChatPlugin.m`

```
#import "LivechatPlugin.h"
#if __has_include(<livechat/livechat-Swift.h>)
#import <livechat/livechat-Swift.h>
#else
// Support project import fallback if the generated compatibility header
// is not copied when this plugin is created as a library.
// https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-static-libraries-dont-copy-generated-objective-c-header/19816
#import "livechat-Swift.h"
#endif

@implementation LivechatPlugin
+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar>*)registrar { <-- ERROR HERE
    [LivechatPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
}
@end
```

Errors 5-1000, 173400-174359
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee7ce5ff8)` in `ios\.symlinks\plugins\livechatt\ios\classes\LiveChatPlugin.m`

```
#import "LivechatPlugin.h"
#if __has_include(<livechat/livechat-Swift.h>)
#import <livechat/livechat-Swift.h>
#else
// Support project import fallback if the generated compatibility header
// is not copied when this plugin is created as a library.
// https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-static-libraries-dont-copy-generated-objective-c-header/19816
#import "livechat-Swift.h"
#endif

@implementation LivechatPlugin
+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar>*)registrar {
    [LivechatPlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar]; <-- ERROR HERE
}
@end
```

Error 174360 `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee7ce5ff8)` in `Runner\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`

```
/* previous code ommitted for brevity */
@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [AppAvailability registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"AppAvailability"]];
  [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"]];
  [FLTGoogleMapsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTGoogleMapsPlugin"]];
  [LivechatPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"LivechatPlugin"]]; <-- ERROR HERE
  [LocationPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"LocationPlugin"]];
  [MsalMobilePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"MsalMobilePlugin"]];
  [FLTPathProviderPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTPathProviderPlugin"]];
  [FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin"]];
  [SqflitePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"SqflitePlugin"]];
  [FLTURLLauncherPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTURLLauncherPlugin"]];
  [FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin"]];
}

@end
```

Could I have some help diagnosing the reason that this error is being thrown in these places, and why it is only affecting the livechatt plugin? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the said package. The issue has been fixed in the latest release. Kindly update the package in your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  livechatt: "^1.1.0"
```